# After forking, are global variables shared?

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork

Consider this simple code:

```
 int myvar = 0;
 int main() {
     if (fork()>0) {
       myvar++;
     } else {
       // father do nothing
     }
 }
```

When child increments myvar, is the value shared with the father (like pthread)?

Comment: I agree with Tom. You could have just output the value from both processes and seen for yourself what the output was. Though remember to sleep in the one that is not expecting an increase in myvar so that it doesn't execute before the other process would (though it won't) increment it. But yeah, just run it and see.

Comment: Note the misleading comment: actually, the parent process increments the counter (unless the fork failed) and the child process does nothing except exit immediately.

Comment: First, you aren’t checking for failure. Second, only file descriptors are shared.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

No and yes.

No, they are not shared in any way which is visible to the programmer; the processes can modify their own copies of the variables independently and they will change without any noticable effect on the other process(es) which are fork() parents, siblings or descendents.

But yes, the OS actually does share the pages initially, because fork implements copy-on-write which means that provided none of the processes modifies the pages, they are shared. This is, however, an optimisation which can be ignored.

If you wanted to have shared variables, put them in an anonymous shared mapping (see mmap()) in which case they really will get shared, with all the caveats which come with that.

Comment: Are you sure about this part `global variable can be shared among parent and child process` ?

Answer (score 46):

`fork()`ing creates an exact copy of the parent process *at the time of forking*.  However, after the `fork()` is completed, the child has a completely different existence, and will not report back to the parent.

In other words, no, the parent's global variables will not be altered by changes in the child.

Comment: +1 Although I would argue that "completely different existence" may be misleading as some objects, such as file-handles, may be shared under different circumstances, IIRC.

Comment: True, each process will have its own handle to any shared resources (files, pipes, etc), as a consequence of the "exact copy".  Not much different, in fact, from two separate processes opening the same file.

Comment: There's one crucial difference between two processes opening the same file and two processes sharing a file descriptor created before forking: the forked processes share the same open file description and offset; if one process moves the file pointer (by reading or writing or seeking), it affects the other too.  This does not happen with separate opens because they have separate open file descriptions.  See: open(), fork(), lseek(), etc.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.  Or, if I did know it, I forgot.  It's been a long time since I've fork()ed.

Answer (score 21):

After fork(), the entire process, including all global variables, is duplicated. The child is an exact replica of the parent, except that it has a different PID(Process Id), a different parent, and fork() returned 0. Global variables are still global within its own process. So the answer is no, global variables are not shared between processes after a call to fork().

Answer (score 12):

No, since global variables are not shared between processes unless some IPC mechanism is implemented. The memory space will be copied. As a consequence, the global variable in both processes will have the same value immediately after fork, but if one changes it, the other won't see it changed.

Threads on the other hand do share global variables.

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether a variable is global or not.

Comment: @tchrist I know, I mention globals because it seems what the op is worried about.