# Can i see a environment variable that was setting in the child process from the parent?

Tags: linux

I'm playing with fork in linux and i see something that don't like me

I read this link [After forking, are global variables shared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298678/after-forking-are-global-variables-shared) and i did a test with gdb

```
[c0m0@worktux programming]$ ps aux | grep env
```

c0m0      3108  0.0  0.0   4288   324 pts/1    S    22:53   0:00 ./env
c0m0      3110  0.0  0.0   4288    80 pts/1    S    22:53   0:00 ./env

[c0m0@worktux programming]$ gdb -q -p 3108
Attaching to process 3108

(gdb) call getenv("toto")
$1 = 4195989
(gdb) x/s $1
0x400695:   "root"

## Now i'll attach to child process

`[c0m0@worktux programming]$ gdb -q -p 3110`

Attaching to process 3110

(gdb) call getenv("toto")

$1 = 4195989

(gdb) x/s $1

0x400695:   "root"

So my what my question is, why i see the variable what i set into fork in the both process?

I used the function putenv for set toto=root, i try to be more clear.

Can i see a environment variable that was setting in the child process from the parent?

Comment: You mean you called `putenv` and then `fork`?  Then of course both of them have the same variable set.

Comment: The answer is still valid, the `fork` function duplicate the process memory (and some other resources like file descriptors) at the time of the fork. This include environment variables.

Comment: I used putenv with fork() { putenv("toto=root"); }, so i know the child receive a copy of parent resources, but i would like to know if enviroment variables of the child process are shared with the parent.

Comment: Even after your edit, it seems to me that the other question answers this one: No, you can't unless you implement something.